# Persisting data in TCP server while client channel is connected

Tags: java, netty

I'm building a TCP Server using Netty.
Is there any way to persist the connected client's session data while its channel exists?

for example, when a client connect to the server, I need to create its class instance and reuse in different ways when he send messages.
something like the code below:

```java
// this is called when the client connect to the server
public void channelActive(final ChannelHandlerContext ctx) {
    ctx.pipeline().get(SslHandler.class).handshakeFuture().addListener(
        new GenericFutureListener<Future<Channel>>() {
            public void operationComplete(Future<Channel> future) throws Exception {
               // I need to create the class instance when the
               // client connects to the server
               ClientData clientData = new ClientData(ctx.channel()); 
               channels.add(ctx.channel()); 
             }
        }
    );
}

// this is called when the server receives a message from the connected client
public void channelRead0(ChannelHandlerContext ctx, String msg) throws Exception {
   if("update".equals(msg)){
       // then I need the retrieve the data created 
       // in the ChannelActive method.
      clientData().update(); 
   }
}
```

While browsing for solutions, I found a few examples where the developer used a cache service (like memcache or redis) to store and retrieve the data related to the connected client.

But I wish to solve this without depending on a external process.
Is there any way to achieve this? Any advice on the subject would be appreciated.

Thank you

Comment: You mean something like a `Map<Channel, ClientData>`?

Comment: To be honest, I had not noticed that could have created the solution using a Map.
I could instantiate a `final static Map <Channel, ClientData>` to create the ChannelHandler, correct? this is a common practice in Netty servers? Thanks!

Comment: I don't know about Netty servers. In straight NIO I would make it the attachment of the SelectionKey. Netty might offer you something similar.

Comment: I'll dig on this. Thank you very much!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use [AttributeMap.attr(AttributeKey key)](http://netty.io/4.0/api/io/netty/util/AttributeMap.html#attr(io.netty.util.AttributeKey)), which is inherited by `ChannelHandlerContext`:

> **Storing stateful information**
>
> `AttributeMap.attr(AttributeKey)` allow you to store and access stateful information that is related with a handler and its context. Please refer to ChannelHandler to learn various recommended ways to manage stateful information. [1]

[1][http://netty.io/4.0/api/io/netty/channel/ChannelHandlerContext.html]

Comment: Thanks @EJP , this is exactly what I needed.